# Is there a way to condense data into one row of a Pandas DataFrame when they share one column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with a few thousand rows.
The DF holds unit identifiers and response times for units within my organization.
It is structured in a DF with columns ["Event#", "UnitID", "First UnitEnroute", "First UnitArrived", "First UnitAtHospital"]

There are many different rows for the same Event#, and in the end I only want one line per Event#, with ["First UnitEnroute", "First UnitArrived", "First UnitAtHospital]" to be filled in by other rows with the same Event#.

The reason for this is some end-of-quarter billing fiasco and we need to know if these different Events have these 3 times spread across the different units. I don't need the units listed though, just the first non 0 value pulled from other rows of the same event.

Here is some example data:

```
Event#      Unit    First UnitEnroute           First UnitArrived           First UnitAtHospital
2020000394    37    ['1/1/2020', '10:45:34 PM'] ['1/1/2020', '10:48:33 PM'] ['1/1/2020', '11:45:01 PM']
2020000394    38    ['1/1/2020', '10:45:34 PM'] ['1/1/2020', '10:48:33 PM'] ['1/1/2020', '11:45:01 PM']     
2020000394    36    ['1/1/2020', '10:45:34 PM'] ['1/1/2020', '10:48:33 PM'] ['1/1/2020', '11:45:01 PM']     
2020000394    39    ['1/1/2020', '10:45:34 PM'] ['1/1/2020', '10:48:33 PM'] ['1/1/2020', '11:45:01 PM']     
2020000617    58    ['1/2/2020', '12:06:13 PM'] ['1/2/2020', '12:07:39 PM'] ['1/2/2020', '12:43:10 PM']     
2020000849    74    ['1/2/2020', '6:42:19 PM']  ['1/2/2020', '6:53:53 PM']  ['1/2/2020', '7:28:32 PM']      
2020000849    75    ['0']                       ['0']                       ['0']
2020000927    81    ['0']                       ['0']                       ['0']
2020000927    80    ['0']                       ['0']                       ['0']
2020000997    86    ['0']                       ['0']                       ['0']
2020000997    87    ['0']                       ['0']                       ['0']
2020001218    99    ['1/3/2020', '11:50:39 AM'] ['1/3/2020', '11:52:40 AM'] ['1/3/2020', '12:29:37 PM']     
2020001218    98    ['0']                       ['1/3/2020', '11:52:40 AM'] ['0']
2020001255    102   ['1/3/2020', '12:44:30 PM'] ['0']                       ['0']
2020001255    103   ['1/3/2020', '12:40:19 PM'] ['0']                       ['0']
2020001258    98    ['1/3/2020', '12:49:00 PM'] ['1/3/2020', '12:57:22 PM'] ['1/3/2020', '1:39:03 PM']      
2020001258    103   ['0']                       ['0']                       ['0']
2020001258    104   ['0']                       ['0']                       ['0']
2020001258    105   ['0']                       ['0']                       ['0']
```

This is what I've tried:

1. Brute force going through every row to find a non 0 value and then append that value to the row.

   ```
    for row in DF:
        compare = list()
        for i in DF:
            if i[0] == row[0]:
                addition = list(i)
                compare = compare.append(addition)
                print("Compare: {}".format(compare))
                return compare

        for el in row.index:
            whatisit = row[el]
            if whatisit == 0:
                for item in compare.index:
                    if item[el] == 0:
                        return
                    else:
                        replacement = item[el]
                        print("Replacement: {}".format(replacement))
                        return replacement
            row[el] = replacement
            return DF
   ```
2. Using pandas.groupby().fillna() to group rows which have have like event#s and backfill with times.
   --I didn't reach any result which was acceptable with this. Most of the time it chopped up my DF into some wonky shapes. I may be misunderstanding how to use this.

```
    DF = DF.groupby("Event#")["Unit", "First UnitEnroute", "First UnitArrived", "First UnitAtHospital"].fillna(method="bfill")
```

Any direction is appreciated, and sorry if this has been posted before, I spent a good deal of time searching for a potential answer. I think I haven't quite developed the intuition I need to see code any see how I can apply it to my project. I am not a developer by trade, I am more of a hands-on lift heavy things sorta employee haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one with, IIUC.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# create data frame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

# drop the column `Unit`
df = df.drop(columns='Unit')

# re-shape
df = df.melt(id_vars='Event#', var_name='first_unit', value_name='timestamp')

# drop timestamp == ['0']
mask = df['timestamp'].astype(str) != "['0']"
df = df[mask]

# drop duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates()

# get min value for each group -- and re-shape
df = (df.groupby(['Event#', 'first_unit'])['timestamp'].min()
      .unstack(level='first_unit')
      .reset_index()
     )

print(df)

first_unit      Event#            First UnitArrived  \
0           2020000394  ['1/1/2020', '10:48:33 PM']   
1           2020000617  ['1/2/2020', '12:07:39 PM']   
2           2020000849   ['1/2/2020', '6:53:53 PM']   
3           2020001218  ['1/3/2020', '11:52:40 AM']   
4           2020001255                          NaN   
5           2020001258  ['1/3/2020', '12:57:22 PM']   

first_unit         First UnitAtHospital            First UnitEnroute  
0           ['1/1/2020', '11:45:01 PM']  ['1/1/2020', '10:45:34 PM']  
1           ['1/2/2020', '12:43:10 PM']  ['1/2/2020', '12:06:13 PM']  
2            ['1/2/2020', '7:28:32 PM']   ['1/2/2020', '6:42:19 PM']  
3           ['1/3/2020', '12:29:37 PM']  ['1/3/2020', '11:50:39 AM']  
4                                   NaN  ['1/3/2020', '12:40:19 PM']  
5            ['1/3/2020', '1:39:03 PM']  ['1/3/2020', '12:49:00 PM']
```

Here is the original data (i.e., used to create the data frame):

```
data = '''Event#      Unit    First UnitEnroute           First UnitArrived           First UnitAtHospital
2020000394    37    ['1/1/2020', '10:45:34 PM']  ['1/1/2020', '10:48:33 PM']  ['1/1/2020', '11:45:01 PM']
2020000394    38    ['1/1/2020', '10:45:34 PM']  ['1/1/2020', '10:48:33 PM']  ['1/1/2020', '11:45:01 PM']     
2020000394    36    ['1/1/2020', '10:45:34 PM']  ['1/1/2020', '10:48:33 PM']  ['1/1/2020', '11:45:01 PM']     
2020000394    39    ['1/1/2020', '10:45:34 PM']  ['1/1/2020', '10:48:33 PM']  ['1/1/2020', '11:45:01 PM']     
2020000617    58    ['1/2/2020', '12:06:13 PM']  ['1/2/2020', '12:07:39 PM']  ['1/2/2020', '12:43:10 PM']     
2020000849    74    ['1/2/2020', '6:42:19 PM']   ['1/2/2020', '6:53:53 PM']   ['1/2/2020', '7:28:32 PM']      
2020000849    75    ['0']                        ['0']                        ['0']
2020000927    81    ['0']                        ['0']                        ['0']
2020000927    80    ['0']                        ['0']                        ['0']
2020000997    86    ['0']                        ['0']                        ['0']
2020000997    87    ['0']                        ['0']                        ['0']
2020001218    99    ['1/3/2020', '11:50:39 AM']  ['1/3/2020', '11:52:40 AM']  ['1/3/2020', '12:29:37 PM']     
2020001218    98    ['0']                        ['1/3/2020', '11:52:40 AM']  ['0']
2020001255    102   ['1/3/2020', '12:44:30 PM']  ['0']                        ['0']
2020001255    103   ['1/3/2020', '12:40:19 PM']  ['0']                        ['0']
2020001258    98    ['1/3/2020', '12:49:00 PM']  ['1/3/2020', '12:57:22 PM']  ['1/3/2020', '1:39:03 PM']      
2020001258    103   ['0']                        ['0']                        ['0']
2020001258    104   ['0']                        ['0']                        ['0']
2020001258    105   ['0']                        ['0']                        ['0']
'''
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like what I need. I am encountering a keyError at the line `df = df.melt(id_vars='Event#', var_name='first_unit', value_name='timestamp')` on `'Event#'`, any idea why that would be?

Comment: Can you execute `'Event#' in df.columns` -- are there any embedded spaces in the column names?  KeyError probably means that the what you're specifying as id_var isn't in df.columns

Answer (score 0):

Since you have few thousand rows, I suggest handling each column separately and merging them together again:

```
df1 = df[ df['First UnitEnroute']!="['0']" ][['Event#', 'First UnitEnroute']]
df1 = df1[~df1.duplicated(['Event#'])]
df2 = df[ df['First UnitArrived']!="['0']" ][['Event#', 'First UnitArrived']]
df2 = df2[~df2.duplicated(['Event#'])]
df3 = df[ df['First UnitAtHospital']!="['0']" ][['Event#', 'First UnitAtHospital']]
df3 = df3[~df3.duplicated(['Event#'])]
df_result = df1.merge(df2, on = 'Event#', how='left').merge(df3, on = 'Event#', how='left')
```

This way (if I have understood the question correctly) you can find the Events that have no timestamps for one or more of the First Unit stats. Which in your sample is event 2020001255